# Javascript - how to not dismiss an alert/confirm window by clicking outside of it?

Tags: javascript, alert, confirm

My Mobile Web Application has an option to enter the developer settings by clicking 6 times in a row on app logo on the top of the display.

Procedure is almost identical to enabling developer settings on Android.

After clicking 6 times, an alert opens up with the information about developer settings being enabled.

However, when a developer wants to enable those settings, he clicks on the logo without counting. The alert window is dismissed almost instantly since it appears after 6 clicks; but 7th click comes really quickly after 6th so the developer can't see the alert appropriately.

How can I make the alert window not dismissed after clicking outside of it? So the developer actually has to press 'OK'?

Comment: Just replace the alert() with an overlay-div which covers the logo and prevents it from being clicked again

Comment: Nice trick, I was looking for something like this

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you cannot...
You have to emulate this behavior with a DOM Dialog